# Retrieve values from db to drop down in ant form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I created a form using this https://ant.design/components/form/ ant template. There for the drop down I need to retrieve values from database. But still I couldn't find a way to achieve.

I am using react js and I could get the values from database inside `componentDidMount()' method. But I couldn't find a way to pass it to the dropdown array defined in ant.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            dropdownItems = [{
                value: array[i],
                label: array[i]
            }
            ];
  }
```

As in the above code I tried it to fetch the result to dropdownItems array. But since dropdownItems is readonly property, it was impossible. So how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

you should store dropdown values in component's state..

```
import { Select } from 'antd';
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          dropdownItems: [],
          selectedValue: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      fetch(api)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(dropdownData => {
         this.setState({ 
           dropdownItems: dropdownData.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item })) }) 
      })
    }

    handleChange = (value) => {
       this.setState({ selectedValue: value })
    }

    render(){
        const { dropdownItems, selectedValue} = this.state;
        return(
          <Select defaultValue={selectedValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            {dropdownItems.map((item, index) => <Select.Option value={item.value} key={index}>{item.label}</Select.Option>)}
          </Select>
        );
    }
}
```